# performSelectorInBackground showing up in > 1 thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, sockets

I'm noticing some odd behavior when I try to dispatch a single thread to poll a unix socket. 
When I test the code out on osx 10.6.8, The code crashes and I see more than 1 thread running the code. 
Oddly enough, on osx 10.7.5, when it crashes, I only see it running on one thread.

In my AppDelegate, I dispatch the thread like this (once) :

```
[pp performSelectorInBackground:@selector(runloop) withObject:nil];
```

pp is an instance of My IPC class.

In my IPC class, the runloop is a wrapper to some C code

```
@implementation IPC
-(void) runloop
{
  ipc_busy = 0;
  unixsocket_runloop();
}
```

The runloop is meant to wait for a single connection (per runtime)
Then the handler waits for packets until the program terminates. 
The C code looks like this -

```
/**
 * Waits for a connection and dispatches the socket handler
 * No need to fork since we will only ever have a single connection per program launch
 */
int unixsocket_runloop()
{
  int connection_fd;
  socklen_t address_length;
  while((connection_fd = accept(socket_fd,
                                (struct sockaddr *) &address,
                                &address_length)) > -1)
  {
    return unixsocket_handler(connection_fd);
  }
  return 0; // for posterity
}
```

This is the connection handler -

```
/**
 * Handles the connection from the client
 * loops infinitely and reads from the socket when there is a message
 * Stores message into a ring buffer of buffers
 */
int unixsocket_handler(int connection_fd)
{
  size_t nbytes;
  char readbuffer[USBUFSIZE];
  bzero(readbuffer,USBUFSIZE);
  while((nbytes = read(connection_fd, readbuffer, USBUFSIZE)))
  {
    // store in buffer
    bufPut(readbuffer,nbytes);
    bzero(readbuffer,USBUFSIZE);
  }
  close(connection_fd);
  return 0;
}
```

In my stack trace, I see this unixsocket_runloop happening in 2 threads. 
While I do not believe this is the root cause for the crashing, 
It is unexpected behavior I would like to address.

The only reason I rolled by own socket class was b/c a lot of the options I'm seeing in the open source community are hard wired to TCP. Especially the appealing cocoaAsyncSocket class.

Comment: The first question is: do both instances of `unixsocket_runloop` have `-[AppDelegate runloop]` as the next thing up the stack? If follow up the stack to see what made that happen. If not (assuming whatever _is_ up the stack couldn't possibly have called `unixsocket_runloop`), it could easily be stack corruption and/or wrong symbols, so you're chasing the wrong goose.

Comment: Each of the stacks from the 2 threads with the runloop appear to be invoked by thread_start -> _pthread_start -> _NSThread__main__ -> unixsocket_runloop. Stack corruption is a great direction to start looking, since the 10.7 related crashes are bailing after a _stk_chk_fail. Thanks for the advice, abarnert.